# R. Extract list from list by logic

Tags: r

I have a list of list containing logical `TRUE`/`FALSE`. How can I extract only lists containing a TRUE value?

Here's my list:

```
jorgelist
# [[1]]
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#
# [[2]]
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#
# [[3]]
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to extract.  Looks like this is only a list and not a list of lists.

Comment: So its a list of logical vectors> str(jorgelist)
List of 49
 $ : logi [1:7] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE ...
 $ : logi [1:9] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE ...
 $ : logi [1:4] FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
 $ : logi [1:8] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ : logi [1:2] FALSE FALSE
 $ : logi [1:2] FALSE FALSE

Comment: What would be the expected output based on the input data

Comment: well that doesn't help much. Include it in your question,.

Comment: Perhaps `jorgelist[sapply(jorgelist, any)]`

Comment: Can I make a logical vector from this list for every vector in the list that has TRUE if there is a TRUE in the vector?

Comment: `sapply(jorgelist, any)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we want to get a logical vector based on `any` TRUE values in the `list` elements,

```
i1 <- sapply(jorgelist, any)
```

This `vector` can be used to extract the elements from another `list` of same `length`

```
anotherlst[i1]
```

Comment: Since the user asked for the extraction of the list, I am adding: 
list.TRUE <- jorgelist[sapply(jorgelist, any)]

Comment: @maRtin I did posted it as a comment earlier, but the OP seemed to want a vector of `TRUE/FALSE`

Comment: Yes I need to use this new list to extract only TRUE from another list of equal length.

Comment: Thank you akrun! The function any() works perfectly!